# How Can I Change PPA Fingerprint

Tags: ppa, packaging, openpgp

I understand that if you create a PPA you have to accept the Ubuntu Code Of Conduct, and that in order to do so you have to register your OpenPGP fingerprint. Now, let's say that I lose my data on my computer, what do I do then in terms of changing the fingerprint. Also, where are these files found in case I want to make a backup. I apologize if this is all very noobish, I am brand new to all of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can walk through Launchpad's [instructions on generating and importing your key](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey) again to do so with a fresh key.  Your key is stored in the `.gnupg` subdirectory of your home directory.